# UITableView: Show selected cell background only when in edit mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When my `tableView` is not in edit mode, I don't want a user to be able to touch the cells and have them highlight. But, because I have set `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` to YES, users can select cells when in editing mode.

How do I only show the cell highlighted view or color ONLY when in editing mode?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is my method that sets `tableView` editing mode:

```
- (void)tableViewEdit {

    if (self.tableView.editing) {
        [self.editButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
    } else {
        [self.editButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Done", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
    }
    [self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];

}//end
```

I also previously set `self.tableView.allowsSelection` to NO as a default, so it will only be YES after editing mode is entered.

Comment: you would be better overriding setEditing, or see my answer for even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting scenario, luckily it's as simple as this:

```
// -tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath: is called when a touch comes down on a row. 
// Returning NO to that message halts the selection process and does not cause the currently selected row to lose its selected look while the touch is down.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return self.isEditing;
}
```

As you can see from Apple's comment shouldHighlight is the first step in the selection process, so that is the place to halt it in the case of table being edited.

Answer (score -1):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if(cell==nil){
     //YOUR inits
  }

  if(self.editing){
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone];
  }else
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleBlue];

  return cell;

}
```

and

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  if(self.editing)return; //NO ACTION
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in my experience, because when going into edit mode `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't get called again and cells don't get redrawn, so they don't know they are suppose to show a color when being touched in edit mode.

Comment: How about `reloading` the table when turning the edit mode ON ?

Comment: That makes the pretty animation go away. Sure, that does work, but I want the animation.